# yii2 Translation framework messages format number

Tags: php, yii2, frameworks, translation, message

I want to change the format number for the translation framework messages. More specifically the validation messages with maximum of characters for a textarea in another language.

For example:
"Description should contain at most 2,000 characters" => "Descripción debería contener como máximo 2000 caracteres".

For this task I have addes to config (web.php):

```
...
'i18n' => [
        'translations' => [
            'yii' => [
                'class' => 'yii\i18n\PhpMessageSource',
                'sourceLanguage' => 'es-ES',
                'basePath' => '@app/messages'
            ],
        ],
    ],
...
```

With this I have created a "yii.php" file at "app/messages/es-ES" with the phrase for translation. This is working.

I have customized the formatting rules in config (web.php) with:

```
...
'formatter' => [
        'class' => 'yii\i18n\Formatter',
        'nullDisplay' => '',
        'thousandSeparator' => '.',
        'decimalSeparator' => ',',
    ],
...
```

But this is not working.

I have installed "PHP intl extension" but this is not working yet.

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: How do you see that it is not working? I believe you have to call the formatter when outputing a value, like this: Yii::$app->formatter->asDecimal(<some value>).

Comment: If I use `Yii::$app->formatter->asDecimal(<some value>)` in a view then it's working but if I have a customized translation file with the next translation `'{attribute} should contain at most {max, number} {max, plural, one{character} other{characters}}.' => '{attribute} debería contener como máximo {max, decimal} {max, plural, one{caracter} other{caracteres}}.',` then the translation is done but the number format it's not working.

Comment: Try replace "{max, decimal}" with "{max, number}". "decimal" is not valid style.

Comment: Sorry, I did serveral test and "decimal" was one of them. If I try "{max, number}" the format is not working yet.

Comment: Seems strange. This line of code works fine for me: `echo Yii::t('app', '{attribute} debería contener como máximo {max, number} {max, plural, one{caracter} other{caracteres}}.', ['attribute' => 'My Attribute', 'max' => 1234]);`. What is your output?